# How to monitor the mouse doubleclick in pynput?

Tags: python, automation, pynput

I am facing a problem when there is a double click during monitoring."can anyone provide me a code that how to monitor **mouse doubleclick** in python using **pynput**?"

Comment: you can always save time when button was clicked and compare it with time of next click - if difference is small enough then you have double click. Problem is when you want to monitor also single click - because it would need run some function which all time checks if time after first click and if there was no next click then treats it as single click.

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy method to get `double click` when you would like get also `single click`.

---

To control `double click` (without controlling `single click`) you can remeber time when was `previous click` and compare with `current click`. If difference is ie. `0.3s` then you can treat it as `double click`.

Code only for left click

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button
import time

previous_left = 0

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global previous_left
    
    #text = 'Pressed' if pressed else 'Released'
    #print('{0} {1} at {2}'.format(text, button, (x, y)))

    double_click_left = False
    
    # double click left button
    if pressed and button == Button.left:
        current_left = time.time()
        
        diff_left = current_left - previous_left
        print('diff left:', diff_left)
        
        if diff_left < 0.3:
            print('double click left')
            double_click_left = True
            
        previous_left = current_left
    
    # other code
    
    if double_click_left:
        # Stop listener
        return False

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    # ... some code ...
    listener.join()
```

Code for other buttons is similar

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button
import time

previous_left = 0
previous_right = 0
previous_middle = 0

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global previous_left
    global previous_right
    global previous_middle
    
    #text = 'Pressed' if pressed else 'Released'
    #print('{0} {1} at {2}'.format(text, button, (x, y)))

    double_click_left = False
    double_click_right = False
    double_click_middle = False
    
    # double click left button
    if pressed and button == Button.left:
        current_left = time.time()
        
        diff_left = current_left - previous_left
        print('diff left:', diff_left)
        
        if diff_left < 0.3:
            print('double click left')
            double_click_left = True
            
        previous_left = current_left
    
    # double click right button
    if pressed and button == Button.right:
        current_right = time.time()
        
        diff_right = current_right - previous_right
        print('diff right:', diff_right)
        
        if diff_right < 0.3:
            print('double click right')
            double_click_right = True
            
        previous_right = current_right

    # double click middle button
    if pressed and button == Button.middle:
        current_middle = time.time()
        
        diff_middle = current_middle - previous_middle
        print('diff middle:', diff_middle)
        
        if diff_middle < 0.3:
            print('double click middle')
            double_click_middle = True
            
        previous_middle = current_middle

    # other code
    
    if double_click_left:
        # Stop listener
        return False


with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    # ... some code ...
    listener.join()
```

---

But problem is when you want also control single click because it would run some function `0.3s` after first click to inform you that it wasn't double click but single click - it would need thread Timer or it would need to run other thread which runs loop wich all time compares curren time with `previous_left` and if there was no click 0.3s after `previous_left` then treats it as single click.

I don't have example for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @furas answer, I wanna suggest how to deal with both single and double click events. You just need to create a function that will create threads, and call it from the listener:

```
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button
import time

previous_left = 0
previous_right = 0
previous_middle = 0
       
def click_handler(x,y,button, pressed):
    x = threading.Thread(target=on_click, args=(x,y,button,pressed))
    x.start()

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    # The code from the comment above to deal with click AND double click
    ...

with Listener(on_click=click_handler) as listener:
    listener.join()
```